# Rendering two div in a div horizantally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent div having two child divs which are in horizantal ,Now I want to add  other div such that the pagination should come.

Here is the code.

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="left"></div>
      <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Here, If i add other div to 'parent',It will append at last,but should not be shown and pagination should come.
Using floats, I am making the div's horizantal.I have to show only two div's,After that pagination should come.

Comment: Please provide more data as to what you're trying to achieve. What it sounds like is that you will most likely need to use javascript to create the desired effect but without having more information it's hard to give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a **DEMO**:

***HTML:***

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">window 1</div>
    <div id="right">window 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="paginator"><span id="prev">Previous</span><span id="next">Next</span></div>
```

***CSS:***

```
#parent {
    width: 850px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #f00
}
#wrapper div {
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px
}
#paginator {
    margin: 10px;
    display: block
}
#paginator span {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    color: #fff;
}
```

***JQUERY:***

```
$(function() {
    $('#next').click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').append($('<div>window 3</div><div>window 4</div>')); // you can add div using other way
        $('#wrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: '-=860px'
        },
        500, 'linear');
    });
    $('#prev').click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: '+=860px'
        },
        500, 'linear');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Bhaskar this is just an example. you have to modify it as your need.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but I'll give it a shot...

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div id="pagination"></div>
```

... is this what you mean to do?